# #!/usr/bin/env Interpreter Arguments -- portable scripts with arguments for the interpreter

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

Because interpreters such as zsh, bash, python, perl may be located in different places on the filesystem, scripts often have a shebang that uses `env` for portability, e.g. `#!/usr/bin/env zsh`.  However, as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)#Portability explains, many systems including Linux don't allow the passing of arguments to the interpreter.

Often, I'd like to do something like `#!/usr/bin/env zsh -f` to prevent my script to ever read my `~/.zshenv`, or I'd like to do `#!/usr/bin/env perl -w`, etc.  This works on OS X, but not on Linux.

What is the workaround for that?  Can I have the best of both worlds: portability and arguments for the interpreter?  If possible, give a general workaround that works for all interpreters, not just zsh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an inline solution to work around the portability problem for ZSH.

```
#! /bin/sh

if [ -z "$IN_ZSH" ]; then
  export IN_ZSH=1
  exec zsh -f "$0" "$@"
fi

## Your ZSH script here
```

Some other methods to try include

- Passing env variables via /usr/bin/env which modify the behavior the same as `--options` such as doing

```
    #! /usr/bin/env POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 bash
```

- Using clever commenting tricks, such as how this script starts out using SH but invokes TCL on the same script

```
    #! /bin/sh
    # \
    TCLBIN=/usr/bin/tclsh; \
    exec $TCLBIN "$0" "$@"
    # Execute the rest via tclsh
    set argc
```

- Setting the option once in the interpreter, if the `--options` being passed in do not affect the **load behavior**

```
    #! /usr/bin/env bash
    # Exit if any error detected
    set -e
```

- For perl, if you're able to use newer versions, this may work in lieu of -w:

```
    #! /usr/bin/env perl
    use warnings;
```

- Using a bootstrap `invoke.sh` script instead of /usr/bin/env to use your PATH, calling with `/path/to/invoke.sh script` with your script starting with `#! zsh -f`

```
    #! /bin/sh

    SCRIPT=$1
    shift 1
    cmd=`sed -n -e 's:#! \?::' -e '1p' $SCRIPT`
    exec $cmd $SCRIPT
```

Comment: For the zsh-specific workaround, I prefer the following myself `[ "x$ZSH_VERSION" = "x" ] && exec zsh -f "$0" "$@"`

Comment: Thanks for the research.  I didn't know that ` #! /usr/bin/env POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 bash` would work.

Comment: I guess there is no single "general solution" that no one else can offer.  So I'll accept your answer.  Hopefully someday Linux gets with the program.

Comment: `#! /usr/bin/env POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 bash` doesn't work as it is as though you wrote `/usr/bin/env "POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 bash" script` at the shell.